# Java open another app as admin

Tags: java, windows

How to in java run another app (.exe) with admin acess? (On windows). I using netbeans idea.

I need open file dialog select .exe and run as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting  it with the terminal:

```
final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", pathToExe);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
final Process p = builder.start();
```